# How do you solve this recursive sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

How do you find the formula for $E_n$ from the following equation

$$E_n = 2 + 3 E_{n-1} + 4\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} E_k \quad (1)$$

where $E_1 = 2$ ?

I actually was able to reduce $E_n$ to a simpler equation:

$$E_n = 4 E_{n-1} + E_{n-2} \quad (2)$$

**My goal is to find $E_n$ in terms of $n$.**

The proof of how I got equation (2) is as follows.
$$E_n = 2 + 3 E_{n-1} + 4\sum_{k=1}^{n-2} E_k \quad (1)$$
$$E_{n-1} = 2 + 3 E_{n-2} + 4\sum_{k=1}^{n-3} E_k$$
$$E_n - E_{n-1} = 3 E_{n-1} - 3 E_{n-2} + 4 E_{n-2}$$
$$E_n = 4 E_{n-1} + E_{n-2} \quad (2)$$

Comment: This might turn into an interesting question: please add more context/your attempts.

Comment: I would expect it to grow faster than any $x^n$ because the last sum gets longer and longer.  A little experimentation shows $\ln(E_n)$ grows faster than linearly but $\ln(\ln(E_n))$ more slowly.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $E_2 = 2 + 3E_1 = 8$, this is just the even Fibonacci numbers $F_{3n}$.

$F_{3n}$ ([A014445](https://oeis.org/A014445)) satisfies $F_{3n} = 4F_{3n-3} + F_{3n-6}$ with the same initial conditions.

Alternatively, from $E_n = 4E_{n-1}+E_{n-2}$ one gets the characteristic equation $r^2-4r-1=0$, which has roots $2\pm\sqrt{5} = \left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^3$. The initial conditions give as the general solution
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left((2+\sqrt{5})^n-(2-\sqrt{5})^n\right),$$
which is the same as $F_{3n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us define $T_n$ as $E_1+\ldots+E_n$. The given recurrence can be written as 
$$\forall n\geq 3,\qquad T_{n}-T_{n-1} = 2+ 3\left(T_{n-1}-T_{n-2}\right)+4 T_{n-2} $$
or as
$$\forall n\geq 3,\qquad T_n = 4T_{n-1}+T_{n-2} + 2.$$
We may easily eliminate the inhomogeneous part by setting $T_n=U_n-\frac{1}{2}$ and getting
$$ \forall n\geq 3,\qquad U_n = 4 U_{n-1}+U_{n-2},\quad U_n=K_+\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{29}}{2}\right)^n+K_-\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{29}}{2}\right)^n .$$
Can you find $K_+, K_-$ by interpolation and finish from here?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I am not knowledgeable enough to know what K+ and K- are. I also don't know enough to find by interpolation. I did however understand everything up to $U_n = 4 U_{n-1} + U_{n-2}$.

Comment: @zmunk: since you can compute the values of $U_0$ and $U_1$ in a explicit way, you can compute the $K_\pm$ constants by solving a simple linear system.